# Translator with HashMap as dictionary Java

Tags: java, hashmap, language-translation

I need to create some kind of translator. I have a HashMap with pairs of Russian and English words as keys and values respectively. When I input a phrase in Russian I need to get English translation or nulls/not found for the words which are not in the dictionary.

So I have such methods for translation:

```
public boolean isInDictionary(String word){
        if(dictionary.containsKey(word)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String translateSentence(String sentence){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String[] splittedStrings = sentence.split( "\n" );

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String s : splittedStrings){
            result.append(translateCheck(s));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public String getWord(String word){
        return dictionary.get(word);
    }
```

Here is how I call these methods:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Translator translator = new Translator();
    System.out.println("Input the phrase to translate:");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(translator.translateSentence(input));
```

When I input distinct word in Russian I get a translation for that, while when I input a phrase consisting of different words I get null.
So what am I doing wrong? I would be grateful for some help!

Comment: you are splitting the sentence by lines instead of words, maybe you wanted `sentence.split(" ")`?

Comment: @LorisSecuro thanks, it helped me. It should be marked as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting the sentence by lines instead of words, probably you wanted to use `sentence.split(" ")` instead of `sentence.split("\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
    public boolean isInDictionary(String word) {
        return dictionary.containsKey(word); //note the removal of the if as it already returns a boolean
    }

    public String translateSentence(String sentence) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String[] splittedStrings = sentence.trim().split(" "); // the actual change

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : splittedStrings) {
            result.append(translateCheck(s));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public String getWord(String word) {
        return dictionary.get(word);
    }
```